# promise chaining and async, await

Tags: reactjs

I have been stuck on this for a while.
In React component I am trying to fetch data from 3 sources and in addition on fetch url depends on another fetch result. Then I'd like to use Promise.all function to setState just one for all three fetch functions.
I have tried to use async/await combination in every possible way but still promises are pending. What am I missing?

```
class DuelDetail extends React.Component {
    state = {
        duel: [],
        dataset: [],
        algorithms: []
    };


    fetchDuel = async () => {
        var dataset = null
        const duelID = this.props.match.params.duelID;
        let duel = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/duel/${duelID}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
            .then(async (res) => {
                    dataset = await this.fetchDataset(res.data.dataset)
                    return [duel, dataset]
                }
            )

    };

    fetchDataset = async (datasetId) => {
        let res = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dataset/${datasetId}`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
        return res

    };

    fetchAlgorithms = () => {
        return axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/algorithm/`,
            {'headers': {'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}})
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        const promises = [this.fetchDuel()[0], this.fetchDuel()[1], this.fetchAlgorithms()]
        Promise.all(promises).then(([duelsResponse, datasetsResponse, algorithmsResponse]) => {
            this.setState({
                duels: duelsResponse.data,
                dataset: datasetsResponse.data,
                algorithms: algorithmsResponse.data
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Running async await wont return a promise, Promise.all needs promise objects.

Comment: In `fetchDuel`, `dataset` is awaited before being returned, which extracts the value from the promise. In addition, no value is returned from `fetchDuel` - you await a `then` promise chain, but then don't do anything with the value. Instead of doing a `then`, you should probably use the value in `duel` after the `get` method. A debugger will show the actual type of the values in these variables and let you step through the flow of the code, which is probably not what you think. `fetchDataset` and `fetchAlgorithms` look okay to me. Also don't call `fetchDuel()` twice - store it in a variable.